# How do I enable edit file and delete file on github.com from a commit?

Tags: github

[image: disabled buttons picture]

I am not sure what do at this point. The buttons are disabled and I can not find any settings to enable them. Could anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Did you try clicking "Load diff" first?

Comment: Also is the PR you're looking at still open?

Comment: I clicked load diff but it can't because the file has too many words. load diff has, unfortunately, nothing to do with it.

Comment: What do you mean by PR?

Comment: Enabling the edit/delete button from a commit has to be somewhere in the settings, I can not seem to find it though.

Comment: I just assumed this was a screenshot from a Pull Request based on the appearance. You cannot edit files on an individual commit, you have to be looking at a branch.

Comment: Hey shim, It's not from a pull request. However, you can edit and delete files from a pull request as I have done it previously. The files in question are from a commit. I see options are available to edit/delete but they seem to be disabled which leads me to believe that you can but I cant seem to find options to enable it. I'm certain I am missing something.

Comment: Yes you can edit files from a PR as that's on an open branch. You cannot edit files on an individual commit in GitHub's web interface. There is no option to enable it.  I recommend you check out [GitHub's support](https://support.github.com/).

Comment: Think about how it would work if you could edit a file at some arbitrary commit — if that file has changed upstream then those changes might be conflicting.